# `which-key` or similar, to show doc strings of commands bound to keys?

Tags: key-bindings, doc-strings

`which-key` [package](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key) is very useful to show the list of command names. Could it (or any other package) also show the doc string of those commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you have [key completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion).

This is similar to `which-key` behavior, but there are differences.

You can use key completion anytime, whether you have already pressed a prefix key or not.  To initiate key completion just hit `S-TAB` (or `M-S-TAB` if in the minibuffer) when you are not otherwise in the middle of completing something. (When you are completing something `S-TAB` performs [apropos completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions).)

Key-completion candidates are the completing key sequence, followed by **`=`**, followed by the name of the command the key sequence is bound to.  For example, if you use `C-x` and then you hit `S-TAB` to complete that prefix key, you see candidates such as these:

`(  =  kmacro-start-macro`

`*  =  calc-dispatch`

`-  =  shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer`

`1  =  delete-other-windows`

`4  =  ...`

The last of these is an example of showing a prefix key.  `C-x 4` is, like `C-x`, a prefix key.  If you choose that candidate then you see all of the completions of that prefix key...

There is also this pseudo key-completion candidate, which is first in the list: **`..`**.  If you choose that candidate then you move up the prefix-key hierarchy, e.g., from the keys that complete, say, `C-x 4` to those that complete `C-x`.

As always in Icicles, you can get the complete doc string (shown in buffer `*Help*`) for any completion candidate, using **`C-M-RET`** or other [candidate-help keys](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos#GetHelpOnCandidates).

In addition, the *first line* of the doc string for the current completion candidate is  shown in the mode-line of the `*Completions*` window.  For a prefix-key candidate the mode-line shows **`Prefix key`**.  And for pseudo-candidate `..` the mode-line shows **`GO UP`**.

So for example, if you cycle among candidates using `down`, `down`, `down`... then you see the first line of each candidate, in turn, in the mode line.  And if you cycle using `C-M-down`, `C-M-down`, `C-M-down`... then you see the complete doc string of each candidate, in turn, in buffer `*Help*`.